# Collation Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I have two databases one is the system database, which has the master database and the other one is my database called `CCTNS_CAS_DE_DB`. When I am trying to generate the reports through the tool which uses the `CCTNS_CAS_DE_DB` database.

I get the following error:

> *Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation*

I went through the SQL Server and checked the properties of the master database it shows the collation as `Latin1_General_CI_AI` but when I went to the properties of the `CCTNS_CAS_DE_DB` database it shows the collation as `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

I searched for the error online but most of the solution tell how to change the collation of a particular table but I didn't come across any query which will change the collation my database to `Latin1_General_CI_AI`.

I came across one query which is:-

```
ALTER DATABASE CCTNS_CAS_DE_DB COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

When I ran this query in my SQL Server it threw the following error:-

> *Msg 5030, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
>   The database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation.
>
>   Msg 5072, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   ALTER DATABASE failed. The default collation of database 'CCTNS_CAS_DE_DB' cannot be set to Latin1_General_CI_AI.*

I know this question has already been posted here but that was in a different context I think.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's the biggest hint to your problem:

> Msg 5030, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 The database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation.

What you need to do is set the database to single-user mode before you run the `ALTER DATABASE` statement, and then set it back to multi-user mode when it's completed. This will lock the database and make it available only to the current connection, which will allow you to successfully run the `ALTER DATABASE ... COLLATE` statement.

You can [use SQL Server Management Studio or T-SQL commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598.aspx) to do this.

Comment: I executed the following query (ALTER DATABASE CCTNS_CAS_DE_DB   
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI ;  
GO ) and was able to change the collation of my db CCTNS_CAS_DE_DB to Latin1_General_CI_AI from SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS but while generating the reports it shows the same error i.e. cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Answer (score 128):

Need to set it to SINGLE_USER first.

```
ALTER DATABASE [database] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 

GO 

ALTER DATABASE [database] COLLATE SQL_1xCompat_CP850_CI_AS; 

GO 

ALTER DATABASE [database] SET MULTI_USER; 

GO
```

Comment: Thanks for not assuming that I knew the SQL to set single-user operation!

Comment: Thanks for not assuming that I knew the SQL to set back to multi-user operation!

Comment: Would be so nice if in 2016, Microsoft could build this simple process into SSMS, instead of leaving it stupid like they did.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to test some accented character insertion out, and this is what I needed for testing, and it turns out it was not the database by the very old AJAX script that was messing things up. Thank you.