# Change database Collation of Azure Devops Server 2019 (on-premises)

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, collation, sql-server-2019

We have an Azure DevOps server 2019 installation on premises running on SQL Server 2019 (15.0.2070.41).
The default collation (I guess based on server regional settings) was ***Greek_CI_AS***.
We noticed that searching work items in azure did not return the correct results when special Greek characters were used. The issue is the wrong collation of the database.
I am trying to change it to ***Greek_CI_AI***.

So what I did was:

1. Tried to change it through DB Properties -> Option -> Collation (didn't work since it was MULTI_USER)
2. Tried to change it to Single User (based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17377732/5386298)

Did not work since there were many dependencies:

```
Msg 5075, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The object 'vw_WorkItemCoreAll' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.
```

Is it possible to change the database collation for Azure? Should I create a new database with the correct collation and migrate there the previous?

Is it possible that configuring/re-indexing the Search component to solve the problem?
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Note: I am also worried if AI is even supported by Azure since Microsoft's recommendation is to choose a collation that is CI, AS
[image]
the text above is from the ([official MS Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/install/sql-server/collation-requirements?view=azure-devops-2019))

Answer (score 1):

It's not able to change this in SQL Server side after you have installed it.

When you install SQL Server, consider two factors regarding collation settings that could affect your Azure DevOps Server deployment:

- Requirements for Azure DevOps Server
- All databases in all instances of SQL Server used by your Azure
  DevOps Server deployment must have the same collation settings.

You can set collation settings for the Database Engine and SQL Server Analysis Services. Collation settings include **character set, sort order, and other locale-specific settings**, that are fundamental to the structure and function of SQL Server databases.

**You cannot change these settings after installation.**

Some *Requirements* for Azure DevOps side.

> To work with Azure DevOps Server, the collation settings for SQL
>   Server must be accent sensitive, case insensitive, and not binary. If
>   multiple SQL Servers are running an instance of Database Engine or SQL
>   Server Analysis Services for Azure DevOps Server, the collation
>   settings must be the same across all these servers.
>
> ......

For more information, see please refer our official doc here--[SQL Server collation requirements, Azure DevOps Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/install/sql-server/collation-requirements?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thank you @PatrickLu-MSFT for your response ! I appreciate it.

Since I used the default settings is it possible now to migrate the data to a new Azure Installation with the correct SQL Collation?

Is it possible since my only concern is the Search Component to reconfigure/edit only this Component?

Comment: @nitse Not much experience with SQL Collation. It's more related to SQL configuration, I often leave it as default value.  `is it possible now to migrate the data to ... with the correct SQL Collation?` It should be, you could easy and safe restore data to a different new installed SQL server. 1. Back up data
 2. Install and configure SQL Server on the new hardware  3. Stop services 4.Restore the databases ...... More detail steps please refer our official doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance?view=azure-devops